# How to reduce code duplication when using non-compatible wrappers

Tags: java, code-duplication

[TL;DR]
The problem is, in `AWrapper` and `AType` I have to duplicate pretty much whole function, where there is always the syntax:

```
public [TYPE/void] METHOD([OPT: args]) throws TestFailedException {
[OPT: TYPE result = null;]
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
while (true) {
  try {
    beforeOperation();
    [OPT: result =] ((WrappedType) element).METHOD([OPT: args]);
    handleSuccess();
    break;
  } catch (Exception e) {
     handleSoftFailure(e);
     if (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime > TIMEOUT) {
       handleFailure(e);
       break;
     } else {
       try {
         Thread.sleep(WAIT_FOR_NEXT_TRY);
       } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
       }
     }
   }
 }
 [OPT: return result;]
}
```

Lets say I have 2 classes I don't own:

```
public class IDontOwnThisType {

  public void doA(String string) { System.out.println("doA"); }
  public String doB();  {System.out.println("doB"); return "doB";}
  public OtherTypeIDoNotOwn doC() {System.out.println("doC"); return new OtherTypeIDoNotOwn();}

}

public OtherTypeIDoNotOwn {

  public void doD() { System.out.println("doD"); }
  public String doE() { System.out.println("doE); }
  public OtherTypeIDoNotOwn  doF(String string) {System.out.println("doF"); return new OtherTypeIDoNotOwn();}

}
```

So, I have an interface:

```
public interface OperationManipulator {

  void beforeOperation(); //called before operation
  void handleSuccess(); //called after success
  void handleSoftFailure(Exception e); //called after every failure in every try
  void handleFailure(Exception e) throws TestFailedException; //called after reaching time limit 

}
```

Then interface that extends above one, "mimicking" methods of external classes, but throwing custom exception:

```
public interface IWrapper<T extends IType> extends OperationManipulator {

  public void doA(String string) throws TestFailedException;
  public String doB() throws TestFailedException;    
  public T doC() throws TestFailedException;

}
```

Then we have `IType`, which also extends `OperationManipulator`:

```
public interface IType<T extends IType> extends OperationManipulator {

  public void doD() throws TestFailedException; 
  public String doE() throws TestFailedException;    
  public T doF(String string) throws TestFailedException;

}
```

Then, we have abstract implementations of above interfaces:

```
public abstract class AType<T extends IType> implements IType{

  Object element; // I do not own type of this object, cant modify it.
  Class typeClass;
  long TIMEOUT = 5000;
  long WAIT_FOR_NEXT_TRY = 100;

  public AType(Object element) {
    this.element = element;
    elementClass = this.getClass();
  }

/* ... */

}
```

Then, we override functions from the interfaces, excluding OperationManipulator interface:

Function not returning anything version:

```
@Override
public void doD() throws TestFailedException {
  long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
  while (true) {
    try {
      beforeOperation();
      ((OtherTypeIDoNotOwn) element).doD();
      handleSuccess();
      break;
    } catch (Exception e) {
      handleSoftFailure(e);
      if (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime > TIMEOUT) {
        handleFailure(e);
        break;
      } else {
        try {
          Thread.sleep(WAIT_FOR_NEXT_TRY);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Function returning normal reference version:

```
@Override
public String doE() throws TestFailedException {
  String result = null;
  long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
  while (true) {
    try {
      beforeOperation();
      result = ((OtherTypeIDoNotOwn) element).doE();
      handleSuccess();
      break;
    } catch (Exception e) {
      handleSoftFailure(e);
      if (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime > TIMEOUT) {
        handleFailure(e);
        break;
      } else {
        try {
          Thread.sleep(WAIT_FOR_NEXT_TRY);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

And function returning object of type parameter:

```
@Override
public T doF(String string) throws TestFailedException {
  T result = null;
  long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
  while (true) {
    try {
      beforeOperation();
      OtherTypeIDoNotOwn temp = ((OtherTypeIDoNotOwn) element).doF(string);
      result = (T) elementClass.getDeclaredConstructor(Object.class).newInstance(temp);
      handleSuccess();
      break;
    } catch (Exception e) {
      handleSoftFailure(e);
      if (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime > TIMEOUT) {
        handleFailure(e);
        break;
      } else {
        try {
          Thread.sleep(WAIT_FOR_NEXT_TRY);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

The same goes for AWrapper, but the differences are:

1. constructor have class argument of stored type
2. object is cast to `IDoNotOwnThisType` instead of `OtherTypeIDoNotOwn`. Functions of this object also may return `OtherTypeIDoNotOwn`.

`IDoNotOwnThisType` is type that `AWrapper` is wrapping.

`OtherTypeIDoNotOwn` is type that `AType` is wrapping.

Then, we have implementation of these abstract classes:

```
public class AssertingType extends AType<AssertingType> {

  public AssertingType(Object element) {
    super(element);
  }

  @Override
  public void beforeOperation() {
    //System.out.println("Asserting type before operation!");
  }

  @Override
  public void handleSuccess() {
    //TODO: add to log file and log to output
    System.out.println("Asserting type success!");
  }

  @Override
  public void handleFailure(Exception e) throws TestFailedException {
    //TODO: add to log file, log to output and throw exception
    System.out.println("Asserting type failure!");
    e.printStackTrace();
    throw new TestFailedException();
  }

  @Override
  public void handleSoftFailure(Exception e) {
    //TODO: add to log file, log to output
    System.out.println("Asserting type soft failure!");
    e.printStackTrace();
  }

}
```

And:

```
public class AssertingWrapper extends AWrapper<AssertingType> {

  public AssertingWrapper (Object driver) {
    super(driver, AssertingType.class);
  }

  @Override
  public void beforeOperation() {
    //TODO
    System.out.println("Asserting wrapper success!");
  }

  @Override
  public void handleSuccess() {
    //TODO: add to log file and log to output
    System.out.println("Asserting wrapper success!");
  }

  @Override
  public void handleFailure(Exception e) throws TestFailedException {
    //TODO: add to log file, log to output and throw exception
    System.out.println("Asserting wrapper failure!");
    throw new TestFailedException();
  }

  @Override
  public void handleSoftFailure(Exception e) {
    //TODO: add to log file, log to output
    System.out.println("Asserting wrapper soft failure!");
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

So, we can use it like that:

```
AssertingWrapper wrapper = new AssertingWrapper(new IDoNotOwnThisType());

AssertingType type = wrapper.doC();

AssertingType type2 = type.doF();
```

Output:

```
Asserting wrapper before operation!
doC
Asserting wrapper success!
Asserting type before operation!
doF
Asserting type success!
```

The full working code is here:
[LIVE](https://ideone.com/MQmnfU)

The problem is, I have always to write `while`, `try` `catch` etc in `AType` and `AWrapper`, can I somehow reduce code duplication? In the example i provided just 3 functions per class, but in my real code I have 50+ methods. Can I somehow wrap these functions so thepart that is repeating is not duplicated?

Comment: can you please give us a TL;DR of all this?

Comment: @MikeNakis provided

Comment: so, did my solution work for you?

Comment: It inspired me much :) I had to add additional functionality to class as whole, so I couldn't just use proxy as you suggested. In the end I wrote a function: `protected Object referenedMethod(Class wrappedInterface, String methodName, Object[] argValues, Function resultConverter)`, and managed to reduce every function code to one-liner :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem appears to be quite complicated, and I cannot claim to have been able to successfully wrap my mind around it, but I will give it a try, because it appears to be a very interesting problem and because I happen to have some experience in dealing with situations that yours appears similar to.

Please excuse me if my answer turns out to be completely off the mark due to a misunderstanding on my part.

So, what it appears that you are looking for is a general purpose solution for injecting your own code before and after an invocation where the invocation may be to any method, accepting any number of parameters, and returning any kind of return value.

In java there exists a dynamic proxy facility, which you can find under `java.lang.reflect.Proxy`.

With it, you can do the following:

```
ClassLoader classLoader = myInterfaceClass.getClassLoader();
T temp = (T)Proxy.newProxyInstance( classLoader, new Class<?>[] { myInterfaceClass }, 
    invocationHandler );
```

The `invocationHandler` is supplied by you, and it is of the following form:

```
private final InvocationHandler invocationHandler = new InvocationHandler()
{
    @Override
    public Object invoke( Object proxy, Method method, Object[] arguments )
        throws Throwable
    {
        /* your pre-invocation code goes here */
        /* ... */

        /* invoke original object */
        Object result = method.invoke( myObject, arguments );

        /* your post-invocation code goes here */
        /* ... */

        /* return the result (will probably be null if method was void) */
        return result;
    }
};
```

So, I think you might be able to use that to solve your problem with the minimum amount of code.

Neither the creation of a dynamic proxy nor the call to `method.invoke()` perform terribly well, (you know, reflection is somewhat slow,) but if you are using it for testing, it should not matter.